# ARM Multi Core SoC's

Tags: arm, rom, core, soc

Is it possible for an additional core to have the same functionality and capability as the main core0 ? So two cores (core0 and core2) performing with the exact same responsibilities and capabilities working in tandem. Taking a device SoC such as in a smart phone with three cores (core0 core1 and core2) for example how can this third core (core2) function and behave in the same manner as the main core0 ? Where would this configuration code be found on die within the core0 embedded circuit code on die ?

Chris thanks. What I am asking is it just in theory and is not likely done in practice but can an extra core be embedded in a multi core SoC device typically found in smart phone devices and have the same control (over IO and CPU executions) over the device as the main or primary core0 ? Could this additional core receive all IO data along with the CPU instructions for the entire device ? I hope this explains the question a little better.

Comment: Your actual question isn't very clear.  If you are asking if all the cores have identical responsibility, they typically do not - one boots first and software on it has discretion to start the others (in some chips a smaller core or special function co-processor has this task).  If you are asking if the cores can function with full independence and no concern for each other, then of course in conventional designs they cannot, since while they might have independent caches, they typically share main memory, external storage, and I/O.

Comment: look up asymmetric multiprocessing.

Comment: This is the latest in a series of weird questions that seem to be based in misunderstanding how CPUs work. If you're asking whether an additional core that "snoops" all IO is possible, the answer is yes.

Comment: Take a look at the TI Hercules processors (ARM Cortex) with 2 cores running in lockstep but 2 cycles apart, so that an electrical event is likely to affect both cores in different manners.